# Rails or node.js for Restful API

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, api, rest, node.js

I have an existing website written in ASP.net, I have recently switched to Mac full time (With Windows in Boot Camp), and need to write a public API for accessing my website's MySQL data. I primarily want to use the API to allow building an iOS application.

I am interested in learning either Ruby on Rails or Node.js, I haven't used either of them yet.

Which language would be better for me to learn?

Comment: What do you want to do on the server side?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have access to both Windows and Linux hosting, so either works for the operating system.

Comment: @spaetzel Means exactly that--it depends on what you actually need it to do--hence my "no better, only more suitable". They're very different beasts, these two things you ask about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails is a **relatively mature** web framework based in Ruby and is designed for handling object-mapped data persistence in a relational database backend.

Node.js is **much newer on the scene**, and unlike Rails, is a more **bare-bones** package that allows for server-side Javascript applications thanks to a pretty tight HTTP(S) API. Node applications are by nature **event-driven**, which may or may not be ideal for your application.

Since it seems that you'll need data-persistence (you mentioned accessing MySQL data...), Rails might be easier to get started with, as it comes packaged with all the things you need in this respect and is designed to facilitate this sort of application.

If you you don't really need relational data persistence, Node is probably a better bet as it stays out of your way and lets you decide how to handle things. It's important to note that Node is a much more bare-bones "framework" than Rails -- if you want something slightly higher-level but still lighter than Rails that runs on Node, [express](http://expressjs.com/) is good place to start.

Still, if you want to try Node (I will confess: it's a lot of fun!), **it's totally possible to access MySQL in a nice, event-driven (non-blocking) way**. Here are two modules that will be helpful:

- [node-dbslayer](https://github.com/Guille/node.dbslayer.js)
- [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

Comment: I think I'll probably go with Node.js. 99% of my requests will be read only, so I'm not too worried about Data persistence. And it does look like fun. Thanks for the link to express, I'll check that out too.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how this works out for you; when you've got something kicking you should update your question with comments about your experience using those MySQL modules. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Neither is a language; they're frameworks. There is no "better", there *may* be a "more suitable" (probably not in this case).

Which would you prefer to develop in, Ruby (Rails), or JavaScript (node.js)?

Would you like to transfer that knowledge to a different job without rampup time (Rails)?

Would you like to learn something a bit more esoteric, event-driven (node.js)? (Ruby has Event Machine, but IMO node.js takes it a bit further.)

Comment: @Raynos Fair enough; environment? Library?

Comment: @Raynos Heh, a bit wordy, but spot-on accurate ;)

Answer (score 2):

So this new application is just a middle man between your ASP.NET thing and your other clients.

In that case, totally use node. Node is great at being networking glue. Node scales great with IO bound applications (i.e. being a network middleman).

If you're going to use node then you probably want to look at [express](http://expressjs.com/) to make it easier.

Comment: Yes, it's to be a middleman between my website and other clients. The data is in MySQL, so the API won't need to talk to ASP.net at all.

Comment: Oh so you want node to talk to the database. Then you may want to look at ruby on rails. Node is better suited to talk to remote connections over networks then generic CRUD to a database

Comment: @Raynos: Unless it has to be faaaast. In that case, node is probably still better.

Comment: @thejh No. MySQL in my node over my dead body. Take this mySQL and put it in rails.

Comment: @Raynos: Why are you hating on node-mysql? :(